# Converting Linear regression with 2 variables to quadriatic model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, nonlinear-regression

now for linear model, the equation is:
`y = w0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2`

I need to convert this to a non-linear model of polynomial degree 2 (quadratic). Would the following be correct?
`y = w0 + w1 x1 + w2 x2 + w3 x1^2 + w4 x2^2`

Comment: a quadratic (second order polynomial) in two variables would normally include the  product term x1.x2 in the predictors as well